# Last line not waiting till long running for loop ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my below jQuery code, I want to show a spinner till the for loop is completed
But due to javascript asynchronous nature, it executes the last line before for loop ends and hides the spinner.

Is there something like callback() available in jQuery? Thanks

```
$('#ajaxSpinnerImage').hide();

$('#bulkUploadButton').on('click',function(){
    $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').show();

    for(var i=0; i < casNumbersArray.length; i++) {
        // Long running operation
    }

    $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').hide(); // How to wait till forloop ends?
});
```

**Update:-**

There is no API involved in the for loop. Just a local array iteration which takes longer maybe a min. And this is a vanilla JS with jQuery

Comment: Just raise a callback after all the for **async** operations finished, and raise the .hide upon that event.

Comment: Which operations do you use in your for body?

Comment: In the for loop, there is no API call, just an iteration on a local array which may take bit longer maybe a min-max.

Comment: @Jay then the spinner shouldn't hide. Are you sure it is showing in the first place? Operations should **never** take that much time, there must be something wrong there. If you don't see the spinner, it's likely that operations are hanging and the page does not respond, perhaps you should share the logic behind the "long running operations".

Comment: If your for loop takes too long without any API  calls, then ajaxSpinnerImage have no chance to display.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should use WebWorkers, but the following might help:

```
$('#ajaxSpinnerImage').hide();

$('#bulkUploadButton').on('click',function(){
    $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').show();

    setTimeout(work, 1);

    function work() {
        for(var i=0; i < casNumbersArray.length; i++) {
            // Long running operation
        }
        $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').hide();
    }
});
```

Try to split your for loop into several pieces. Otherwise, I think, your UI might be unresponsive for the time of this for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient solution, but try [jQuery's When](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Also as others have suggested, if you have a long running thread, in order not to freeze the UI and degrade user experience, use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

```js
    $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').hide();

 $('#bulkUploadButton').on('click',function(){
     $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').show();

      $.when(longRunningOperation()).done(function(  ) {
     $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').hide(); // How to wait till forloop ends?
  });

        function longRunningOperation() {
     for(var i=0; i < casNumbersArray.length; i++) {
        // Long running operation
      }
     }
     
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple way using a conditional. If you have racing conditions you can use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to resolve all completions  or you can use jquery [deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

If the user interface is lagging while processing the long calculations, you should use [web-workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to relieve the main thread

```js
var casNumbersArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

$('#ajaxSpinnerImage').hide();

function longOperation (i) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i == casNumbersArray.length - 1) {
    $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').hide(); 
    console.log('finished');
  }
}

$('#bulkUploadButton').on('click',function(){
    console.log('start');
    $('#ajaxSpinnerImage').show();

    for(var i=0; i < casNumbersArray.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(longOperation.bind(this, i), i*1000);
        // perform one operation per second
    }

});
```

```css
#ajaxSpinnerImage {
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px; height: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 4px;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {transform: rotate(0)}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="bulkUploadButton">Start long operation</button>
<div id="ajaxSpinnerImage">ⓞ</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can slightly change the code to run async operations in parallel:

```
async function processArray(array) {
  // map array to promises
  const promises = array.map(delayedLog);
  // wait until all promises are resolved
  await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log('Done!');
}
```

This code [last line no longer available](https://wikiguide.tips/how-to-fix-last-line-no-longer-available-on-iphone)
will run many delayLog tasks in parallel. But be careful with very large array (too many tasks in parallel can be too heavy for CPU or memory).

Also don’t confuse “parallel” here with real threads and paralleling. That code will not guarantee real parallelism of execution. It depends on your item function (delayedLog in this demo). Network requests, webworkers and some other tasks can be executed in parallel.